# Configure ember-cli version >= 3 to use native async/await and generators

Tags: javascript, ember.js, async-await, ember-cli, babeljs

How to configure ember-cli version >= 3 to use native async/await and generators without babel regenerator polyfill and async/await transpiling.

Answer (score 0):

At this time, I would recommend using [babel-preset-modern-browsers](https://github.com/christophehurpeau/babel-preset-modern-browsers) if you really only want to target modern browsers on the desktop.

If you would prefer to stick to [babel-preset-env](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-env), then edit your `targets.js` to the following:

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "targets": {
        "browsers": ["last 1 versions"]
      },
      "exclude": ["transform-async-to-generator"]
    }]
  ]
}
```

The exclude option is being used here to forcibly not use that particular transform.